# No limits on throw exception types

Tags: c++, exception, throw, exception-specification

I have learned that when i specify the kind of exception the function can throw
no others can be thrown, but when i tested this code it didn't follow this rule.

```
void foo(int i)throw(int)
{
    if(i==2)
    {
        throw("exception");
    }
}
int main()
{
    int i=2;
    try
    {
        foo(i);
    }
    catch(const char* ex)
    {
        cout<<ex<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Have I misunderstood something?

Comment: Exception specifications were never implemented correctly by most of the compilers and C++11 deprecates them(not entirely but atleast your use case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

exception specifications work not as you thought.

You can still throw any exception, but if you actually allow anything unlisted to escape you will get a call to `unexpected()` and `terminate()`.

It's common mistake to think exception spec is similar to java one, it is not. Most guidelines state to not use them, maybe beyond throw(). Some compilers are *specified* to not implement them (check MSVC dox if you use that one). They are deprecated in the current standard (C++11).  __noexcept(true/false) carries ahead the sensible use case.

Comment: Well why and how should I use exception specifications? what is the use of them?

Comment: simply put you shouldn't. Read these: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill22.htm http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/082.htm http://boostjp.github.io/more/lib_guide.htm#Exception-specification

Comment: Thx mate thats realy helpfull.